# After URL rewrite, prevent accessing page using file extension

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on .htaccess development for one of my websites. So far, here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
# omit www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# now omit.php extension from page names
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This all works fine, the site is served up sans `www.` and all the `.php` extensions are removed. I also removed the `.php` extensions from my page links in the markup, and again, the pages are served up as I want, for example, what was `website.com/news.php` now shows as `website.com/news`

Cool.

What I next realized was that the pages were still able to be accessed by typing in the page name with the file extension, so `website.com/news.php` pulls up the page with the file extension in the address bar as `website.com/news.php`

Is there a way to prevent this? So that if `website.com/news.php` is entered into the address bar, the browser will serve up `website.com/news`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if `website.com/news.php` is entered into the address bar, the browser will serve up `website.com/news`:

Sure you can add a redirect rule to remove `.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# omit www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

# To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I didn't see your post until today, I'll give it a try now and let you know how it works, thank you!

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much for the help! Now I've got to study the code to fully understand how it works. Many, many thanks!