# Remove index from URL after file extension has been removed using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With help on my last question about removing file extensions from the address bar if the page name and file extension were keyed in directly even after using htaccess to remove them, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602192/after-url-rewrite-prevent-accessing-page-using-file-extension/42605000#42605000) I'm now wanting to remove `index` from the url. Specifically, if I type in my webpage's URL into a browser like so: `http://webpage.com` that exact address is what I see in the browser when the page is served up. However, if I click the `Home` link on my page, which contains `a href="index"` naturally, what shows in the address bar is `http://website.com/index` Certainly, I could change the link in my code to `a href="http://website.com"` to omit the `index` portion from showing up in the address bar, but that seems like a hack.

I found an SO article [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567652/how-do-you-remove-inex-php-from-a-url-using-mod-write-while-still-allowing-php) that shows a method for removing `index.php` but I'm a bit lost as to how, or even if the code in that answer (I get particularly stuck when seeing `Rewrite Base /`
) can be blended in with the code that was given to me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602192/after-url-rewrite-prevent-accessing-page-using-file-extension/42605000#42605000) to just remove `index` after the file extensions have already been removed.

My apologies in advance if this isn't a clear explanation, I'm in new territory here. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing proper rewriting requires you to build the correct links that you want to see being used by the web (i.e. users and search engines). Don't use URLs in your own links that point to URLs that you consider to be wrong.

The link to the home page likely should be `<a href="/">`, if you don't like `index`.

Trying to fix the problem by making the client do two requests, one for `index`, then receiving a redirect to `/`, is the hack here. Fix your links - they are under your control for a reason.

Comment: Brilliantly put. Thank you for the simple solution I was vastly overlooking!

Answer (score 0):

```
Certainly, I could change the link in my code to a href="http://website.com" to omit the index portion from showing up in the address bar, but that seems like a hack.
```

No, that's what I would do :-)